# Field 'id' expected a number but got 'on'

Tags: python, django, python-3.6, web-frameworks

I am doing a project included in Django Documentation.

When I enter URL `http://localhost:8000/polls/1/vote/` I will get the error at below line:

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'on'

Below lines are my view definition:

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except(KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

Comment: is it a POST request you are making? Please give the complete request/error/response!

Comment: could you show the error message as well?

Comment: `selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])`

Comment: `print(request.POST.get('choice'))` ... printing is the simplest form of debugging you have ... my guess is that the value is "on" ... pk expects a number

Comment: **The above exception (invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'on') was the direct cause of the following exception: **

Comment: pk is a primary key for id of votes @JoranBeasley

Comment: ... which is a number ... `"on"` is not a valid number so it doesnt know you are asking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have sent the value `"on"` in a post message with the field `request.POST["choice"]` , which is not a valid pk for `selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])` which expects a number

Comment: It just got fixed. I had forgot to include `value="{{ choice.id }}"` in my HTML file

Comment: so you were sending the option value of `"on"` as my answer stated?

Comment: Yes actually. I am newbie to Django and Doing my first project by referring to its documentation.

Comment: just follow it closely ;P dont skip ahead or veer off path